# How to find the widest range in rent prices?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to find the widest range of rent prices from different buildings.

Apartment table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE apartment
(   buildingid      CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
aptno       CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
anoofbedrooms   INT     NOT NULL,
ccid        CHAR(4),
rent INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B1','11',1,'C111',1000);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B1','21',1,'C111',1050);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B1','31',1,'C333',1100);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B1','41',1,null,1200);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B1','51',1,null,1010);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B2','11',2,'C222',1200);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B2','21',2,'C222',1300);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B2','31',2,null,2000);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B2','41',2,null,1000);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B2','51',2,'C111',1080);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B2','61',2,'C111',1500);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B3','11',2,'C777',1400);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B3','21',2,'C777',1005);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B3','31',2,'C555',2200);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B3','41',2,'C555',2030);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B4','11',2,'C777',2400);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B4','21',2,'C777',2050);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B4','31',2,'C222',2600);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B4','41',2,'C222',2070);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B5','11',3,'C555',2800);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B5','21',3,null,3800);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B5','31',3,'C111',1800);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B6','11',1,'C111',2200);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B6','12',1,'C111',2300);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B6','21',1,'C444',2400);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B6','22',1,'C444',2500);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B6','31',1,'C555',2600);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B6','32',1,'C333',2700);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B7','11',3,'C999',2800);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B7','12',3,'C999',800);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B7','13',3,'C999',900);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B7','21',3,null,700);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B7','22',3,'C222',600);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B7','23',3,'C111',860);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','11',2,'C777',870);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','12',2,'C777',880);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','21',2,'C444',1890);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','22',2,'C444',2890);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','31',2,null,1840);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','32',2,null,1830);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','41',2,'C666',1830);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B8','42',2,'C666',1830);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B9','11',2,'C111',2800);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B9','21',2,'C222',1890);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES ('B9','31',2,'C222',890); `
```

I tried to using the max function. but not sure it will gave me the widest range. What is the function to find the widest range between set of numbers and buildings?

```
SELECT buildingid, max(rent) as rent
FROM apartment
group by buildingid
```

Than you for your help!!

Comment: I see no attempt here to solve the problem stated.

Comment: Define range. Define widest range.

Comment: its the highest rent and the lowest rent.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result for this sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get minimum and maximum rent for all buildings:

```
select buildingid, min(rent) min_rent, max(rent) max_rent
from apartment
group by buildingid
```

If you want the building with the greatest range, add:

```
order by max_rent-min_rent desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are also interestet which appno get the lowest and highest rent

> ```
> SELECT a.buildingid, aptno,rent, maxrent, minrent as rent
> FROM apartment a
> inner Join (SELECT buildingid, MAX(rent) maxrent,MIN(rent) minrent FROM apartment group by buildingid) b 
> on a.buildingid = b.buildingid and (a.rent = b. maxrent or a.rent = b.minrent)
> ```
>
> ```
> buildingid | aptno | rent | maxrent | rent
> :--------- | :---- | ---: | ------: | ---:
> B1         | 11    | 1000 |    1200 | 1000
> B1         | 41    | 1200 |    1200 | 1000
> B2         | 31    | 2000 |    2000 | 1000
> B2         | 41    | 1000 |    2000 | 1000
> B3         | 21    | 1005 |    2200 | 1005
> B3         | 31    | 2200 |    2200 | 1005
> B4         | 21    | 2050 |    2600 | 2050
> B4         | 31    | 2600 |    2600 | 2050
> B5         | 21    | 3800 |    3800 | 1800
> B5         | 31    | 1800 |    3800 | 1800
> B6         | 11    | 2200 |    2700 | 2200
> B6         | 32    | 2700 |    2700 | 2200
> B7         | 11    | 2800 |    2800 |  600
> B7         | 22    |  600 |    2800 |  600
> B8         | 11    |  870 |    2890 |  870
> B8         | 22    | 2890 |    2890 |  870
> B9         | 11    | 2800 |    2800 |  890
> B9         | 31    |  890 |    2800 |  890
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed7c8fd8a4e240cbe9879ddfdf6aa5b5)*